# How would I describe someone who is coding a new app? It’s for a story I’m writing but just can’t think

Tags: creative-writing

I need to write about someone coding an app but I’m not tech-y. Someone please help

Comment: You want a word that describes the person or the job? e.g. geek or developer.

Comment: Just call him a *[app] **coder*** and be done with it.

Comment: Are you looking for title (developer, programmer, etc) or an activity (coding, developing, inventing)?

Comment: I would say to avoid "coder". Knowing and following a lot of people working in tech, it's a word that is basically _never_ used in the industry. Most people say "developer", "app developer", sometimes "engineer". As for the verb, a simple "create" or "develop"  or "work on" will do.

Comment: From the job itself (mine) I would say that they are *Programming*.